# I want to create a merged multi column header

Tags: tables, graphics

[image]

This is the image of table.
Can anyone help me create a multi column header ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! We can help, but what have you done? What don't you know how to do it?

Comment: I can not make the multicolumn table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}Utente & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Parte pubblica} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Parte segreta}\\\hline
Aldo & N & e &p,q [N=p*q] & b = $\Phi$(N) & d\\\hline
Esempio& 55 & 3 & 5, 11 [55= 5*11] & 40 = $\Phi$(55) & 227\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user136717 you're welcome : )

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}
Utente &\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Parte pubblica} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Parte
segreta}\\
\hline
\color{blue}Aldo &N &e &p, q &b=Q &d\\
\hline
Esem &55 &3 &5, 11 &40 &27\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alongside the other answers, you can also use [Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/).
It provides the source code, you just need to copy it to clipboard.

Comment: didn't know this website, cool!

Answer (score 2):

one more example ... (with subtle improvements)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{2.5em}|p{2.5em}|l|l|l|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}
Utente  &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Parte pubblica} 
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Parte segreta}              \\
    \hline
Aldo    & N     & e & p, q~ $[N=pq]$        & $b=\Phi(N)$   & d     \\
    \hline
Esempio & 55    & 3 & 5, 11 $[55=5\cdot11]$ & $40=\Phi(55)$ & 227   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `tabularx` so that columns 2 and 3 have equal widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\myheadfont{\itshape\bfseries}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myhead}{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\myheadfont#2}}

\usepackage[table, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\centering\begin{tabularx}{0.88\textwidth}{|l|X|X|*{3}{l|}}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!35!Lavender}\myheadfont{Utente} & \myhead[2]{Parte pubblica} & \myhead[3]{Parte segreta} \\\hline
  \rowcolor{Lavender!15}Aldo & N & e & p,q [N=p*q] & b = $\Phi$(N) & d \\\hline
  \rowcolor{Lavender!15}Esempio & 55 & 3 & 5, 11 [55= 5*11] & 40 = $\Phi$(55) & 227 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions (indeed I prefer the first):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\hfil}X>{\hfil}Xllll}
\toprule
\slshape Utente &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape Parte pubblica} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\slshape Parte segreta}\\
\cmidrule(rl){1-1}
\cmidrule(rl){2-3}
\cmidrule(rl){4-6}
Aldo & N & e &p,q [N=p*q] & b = $\Phi$(N) & d\\
Esempio& 55 & 3 & 5, 11 [55= 5*11] & 40 = $\Phi$(55) & 227\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
>{\columncolor{orange!10}}l
>{\hfil\columncolor{cyan!10}}X
>{\hfil\columncolor{cyan!10}}X
>{\columncolor{gray!20}\color{black!60}}l
>{\columncolor{gray!20}\color{black!60}}l
>{\columncolor{gray!20}\color{black!60}}l}
\specialrule{1pt}{2pt}{0pt}
\rowcolor{blue!10}
\slshape Utente &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\slshape Parte pubblica} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\slshape Parte segreta}\\
\specialrule{.4pt}{0pt}{0pt}
Aldo & N & e &p,q [N=p*q] & b = $\Phi$(N) & d\\
Esempio& 55 & 3 & 5, 11 [55= 5*11] & 40 = $\Phi$(55) & 227\\
\specialrule{.8pt}{0pt}{2pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```